# How to save data from dynamic form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, controller

I encountered a problem saving the data from the form into my database. read a lot of manuals and articles and I have not found a suitable me information. Problem:

I have a database:

```
create_table "product_storage", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer   "pro_size_id"
  t.integer   "pro_color_id"
  t.integer   "product_id"
  t.integer   "count"   
end
```

When adding / editing a product, you need to make a dynamic form for storage. I suppose that the cell should look like this:

```
 #app/products/new.html.haml
   ...
   %p
     = f.label :colors
     %br
     = f.fields_for @storage do |color|
       = color.collection_select :pro_color_id, ProductColor.order(:title), :id, :title, include_blank: 'Select color...'
   %p
     = f.label :sizes
     %br
     = f.fields_for @storage do |size|
       = size.collection_select :pro_size_id, ProductSize.order(:title), :id, :title, include_blank: 'Select size...'
```

This fields send request:

```
"product_storage"=>{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"1"}
```

Question How do I make a form that will send an array or hash, and then save it as a database from a controller?
Ideally, to look something like:

```
"product_storage"=>[
{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"1"},
{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"2"},
{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"3"}
],
```

to break it down into the controller via the method each. But i don't now how.

Comment: Did not understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: array of hash? like what?

Comment: Ideally, to look something like: 

    "product_storage"=>[{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"1"},{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"2"},{"pro_color_id"=>"1","pro_size_id"=>"3"}]

to break it down into the controller via the method each. But i don't now how.

Comment: from what I understand you want to create multiple objects on one submit, am I right?

Comment: yes and stored in separate cells of the database (rather than one field)